# Counting integer frequency through pipe

Tags: bash, hashmap, pipe

**Description**

I have a for loop in bash with 10^4 iterations in total. Each iteration a list of roughly 10^7 numbers is generated from a pipe, each number an integer between 1 and 10^8. I want to keep track of how many times each integer appeared. The ideal output would be a .txt file with 10^8 lines, each line containing a counter for the integer corresponding to the row number.

As a significant proportion of integers do not appear while others appear nearly every iteration, I imagined using a hashmap, so as to limit analysis to numbers that have appeared. However, I do not know how to fill it with numbers appearing sequentially from a pipe. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Reproducible example:**

sample.R

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
n_samples = as.numeric(args[1])
n_max = as.numeric(args[2])
v = as.character(sample(1:n_max, n_samples))
writeLines(v)
```

for loop:

```
for i in {1..n_loops}
do
    Rscript sample.R n_samples n_max | "COLLECT AND INCREMENT HERE"
done
```

, where in my case n_loops=10^4, n_samples=10^7, n_max = 10^8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple Approach

Before doing premature optimization, try the usual approach with `sort | uniq -c` first -- if that is fast enough, you have less work and a shorter script. To speed things up without too much hassle, set the memory using `-S` and use the simplest text encoding `LC_ALL=C`.

```
for i in {1..10000}; do
    Rscript sample.R n_samples n_max
done | LC_ALL=C sort -nS40% | LC_ALL=C uniq -c
```

The output will have lines of the form `number_of_matches   integer_from_the_output`. Only integers which appeared at least once will be listed.

To convert this format (inefficiently) into your preferred format with 10<sup>8</sup> lines, each containing the count for the integer corresponding to the line number, replace the `... | sort | uniq -c` part with the following command:

```
... | cat - <(seq 100''000''000) | LC_ALL=C sort -nS40% | LC_ALL=C uniq -c | awk '{$1--;$2=""}1'
```

This assumes that all the generated integers are between 1 and 10<sup>8</sup> inclusive. The result gets mangled if any other values appear more than once.

### Hash Map

If you want to go with the hash map, the simplest implementation would probably be an `awk` script:

```
for i in {1..10000}; do
    Rscript sample.R n_samples n_max
done | awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (ln=1; ln<=100000000; ln++) print int(a[ln])}'
```

However, I'm unsure whether this is such a good idea. The hash map could allocate much more memory than the actual data requires and is probably slow for that many entries.

Also, your `awk` implementation has to support large numbers. 32-bit integers are not sufficient. If the entire output is just the same integer repeated over and over again you can get a up to ...

> 10<sup>4</sup> iterations * 10<sup>7</sup> occurrences / iteration = 10<sup>4+7</sup> occurrences = **10<sup>11</sup> occurrences**

... of that integer. To store the maximal count of 10<sup>11</sup> you need at least 37 bits > log<sub>2</sub>(10<sup>11</sup>) bits.
GNU awk 5 on a 64-bit system seems to handle numbers of that size.

### Faster Approach

Counting occurrences in a data structure is a good idea. However, a hash map is overkill as you have "only" **10<sup>8</sup> possible values** as output. Therefore, you can use an array with 10<sup>8</sup> entries of 64-bit counters. The array would use ...

> 64 bit * 10<sup>8</sup> = 8 Byte * 10<sup>2+6</sup> = 800 MByte

... of memory. I think 800 MByte should be free even on old PCs and Laptops from 10 years ago.

To implement this approach, use a "normal" programming language of your choice. Bash is not the right tool for this job. You can use bash to pipe the output of the loop into your program. Alternatively, you can execute the for loop directly in your program.